# Continuous Server Client Communication via sockets or callbacks

Tags: java, android, ios, web, server

SO, I wish to ask something I cannot get my head around. For example I have an application which is required to track APPLICATION_1 location and the location is being updated at Firebase RealTime Database, which further is consumed by my server. Now I wish to show this continuous location on TWO other applications. Doing some Rnd I came to know of socket implementation but consider I have 200 users using APPLICATION_1, and continuously feeding data to Firebase DB and then this being fed further to 400 end users via server, meaning maintaining or keeping 400 sockets opened for this very purpose. This seems like a very bad option for my server as it will get lagged and might end up being unresponsive. However, if I use alternate Callback recursive API that pings the server for the realtime location of 200 users of APPLICATION_1 that too is a horrible solution. I am kind of stalled in which approach to take when implementing a solution for this specific problem. The limitation is that I have only 1 server and 3 applications to feed data to, which further can be used by many users.

**UPDATE**

Well after much contemplation I came to these following conclusions:

1. Establish Kafka connections:
   As Youtube does it or other streaming data sites, the platform needs to cache its resources and submit it over a stream, as it is being currently done by Kafka. So there would be a need to write a wrapper for Kafka stream on all platform ends, like web wrapper, ios and android wrappers as well. However what Youtube does is, it initially makes a one to one connection between the client and the server no matter how long the distance is, but as Youtube is a much BIGGER platform, if it feels there are more users using this stream, it makes copy of the actual stream and publishes it on a nearby server where the clients receiving it from that locality are shifted to. This we cannot do as we have limited server functionality.
2. Implement Callbacks API:
   Well implementing Callbacks API initially seemed very recursive and bad implementation, but afterwards I researched it for the internet of things platform and discovered IOT implements another protocol of API calls, [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/), which is a much lighter, durable and not resource hungry solution. However this too requires Promises (need to dive into this more).
3. Getting Firebase Realtime Database Feed directly:
   Firebase RealTime Database provides real time synching and seems the best alternate, however consider if 200 users of APPLICATION_1 are updating FireBase RDB, the cost is only for those 200 users using APPLICATION_1, whereas when 200 APPLICATION_2 users and 200 APPLICATION_3 users are fetching the data off the the same DB, it takes the total nodes to 600 and that can be pretty pricy. Firebase's scalability is of the issue here.
4. Socket Implementation:
   Sockets are port hungry. Although their one to one connection is seamless and communication perfect, they tend to become a problem when the number of nodes increases dramatically. Hence if the server is being used for a multitude of data handling process, this might not be the perfect solution.

Comment: Firebase might not be the best for such a heavy continuous realtime database usage. Watch this video to get some insight: https://youtu.be/6NegFl9p_sE?t=428

Answer (score 0):

Best scenario for this to to use a sort of a timer
you keep the location data record locally and only send every X minutes or whatever suits you
and the receiving app also updates every X minutes 
Also please note the Socket connection has been limited from android 7
check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49016500/1849543

Comment: I understand your insights, thank you for them :) however I don't think they kind of propel me towards a proper solution. I did however end up doing some Rnd and came to some conclusion which I am going to update in my question, please have a look.